# storing and displaying image from database

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to display an image trough php. I have the filepath of the image tsored in my table under 'imglink' but I can't display it with echo. 
Can you give me some suggestions on how exactly to do it? My code is below. 
Also when i'm soring the filepath does it need to be the full path C:.....etc or can it just be the folder with the images?
Thank you

```
$sql = "SELECT `Name`, `Location`, `Description`, `Airport`, `imglink` FROM `attractions` WHERE `Category`='HistV'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

    if (!$result) 
    {
        echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
        echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        echo $row['Name'];
        echo "<img src=\"{$row['image']}\" />";
    }
```

Comment: It just needs to be the web path the image `/images/filename.jpg`

Comment: What are the curly braces doing in there? Is this php or handlebars? If it's php, then you need something like this: `src="<php echo $row['imglink']; ?>"`...

Comment: It is still not showing the image

Comment: What is output when you run the code?

Comment: It outputs the first echo (the one for the name) and the nothing.

Comment: look at my answer, that's because your img tag is all messed up with the php part

Answer (score 1):

You use 'image' in the result row, but in your query it's 'imglink'.

```
echo "<img src='" . $row['imglink'] . "'>";
```

should work as long as that row actually has proper path.
To check whether the path is correct or not -simply print it out.
The path should be relative to whatevere page you are calling it from.

Answer (score 0):

If your 'image' is stored in the format name.jpg then what you are after is:

```
echo '<img src="'.$row['image'].'">';
```

Hope that helped!